# Restricting a new WiFi device to WPA2 only

Tags: wifi

I am currently in a discussion with some colleagues about the development of a solution that includes WiFi. They say that it is not state of the art if we implement all of the possible WiFi encryption methods, including Open and WEP. So, they want to restrict the device to WPA2 only.

It doesn't seem logical to me because I have never seen this approach in any solution before (for example: phones)

Is it correct to develop a Wifi device that has only WPA2 in it to prevent WiFi vulnerabilities?

Comment: There is nothing known about your solution and specifically not about its security requirements. Therefore it cannot be determined if open WiFi is a security problem or not. This makes the question too broad. What can be said is that WEP should better not be used, i.e. if you need encryption than do it right.

Comment: I did it on purpose because i wanted to know if there is even a possible implementation of only one Encryption protocol because i have never seen one. and if yes why the phones and other devices that we use all the encryption protocols are enable (even the insecure ones) while they are not state of the art

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open and WEP are enabled on ***personal consumer devices*** because the maker has no control over how the device will be used or what networks it might connect to.

Device manufacturers who can and do control how the device is used will certainly make a risk assessment and a benefits assessment to restrict the device to only the functions that are required and restrict the functions that it simply does not need.

So, the question is not about "state of the art", the question is only about how it will be used and the benefits/risks assessment about which functions it needs to have for the device to accomplish its goal.